# How to construct tables with variable width

Tags: tables

I would like to construct following table:[image]

Kindly suggest me some way to do the same.

This is my try:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
$B_{int}$= \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
$B_{CVP}$ &            & $t$ \\ \hline
          & $B_{BCH}$ & $s$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Basically, I don't know how to assign variable width and height.

Comment: Please add what you've got so far and which part of the shown tables troubles you. The pictures just show two figures which should be achievable using ordinary `tabular` and its width-dependent column types in combination with some tikz.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). What have you done so far? Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: You could also use a [`tikz` `\matrix`](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/matrix-multiplication/).

Comment: For variable width and height you can use `p{width}` as column type  for the width and a `\vspace*{height-contentheight}` as filler for the height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the general question here is to create a tabular cell with a specified width and height with the content centralised both horizontally and vertically. There are some other parts needed also to recreate the picture but I will concentrate on the cell. There are some different settings to get a cell with a certain width, the most obvious is `p{2cm}` which is a paragraph of width 2cm.

In the `array` packet there are some more, where `m{2cm}` is useful here. The contents is vertically centered and left align in a cell of width 2cm. To get the horizontal center, specify a column type like

```
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
```

where `T{2cm}` gives the desired cell. Then to give the height of the cell I specify a new column type

```
\newcolumntype{E}[1]{@{}m{0pt}@{}}
```

which is a cell of no horizontal space. Then I set a zero width rule (black box) of the height I want. This will span the row in the desired height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{E}[1]{@{}m{0pt}@{}}
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{document}
A
\begin{tabular}[c]{| E | T{3cm} |}
  \hline
  \rule{0pt}{2cm} & B \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the picture the horizontal spacing is not really needed to set, it can follow the content in other cells in the row. But the centering as above can be used, but since it is math formulas I alter it to `array` instead of `tabular`. So parts of the picture can be done as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{E}[1]{@{}m{0pt}@{}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}m{#1}<{$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
  B_{\mathrm{BCH}}=
  \begin{array}[c]{|E|M{2.7cm}|M{2.5cm}|M{1cm}|M{0.8cm}|}
    \cline{1-3}\cline{5-5}
    & QP_{\mathrm{BCH}}
    &
      \setlength\arraycolsep{3pt}
      \begin{matrix}
        2Q & & & \\
        & 2Q & & \\
        & & \ddots & \\
        & & & 2Q
      \end{matrix}
      & &
          Qs'
    \\\cline{1-3}\cline{5-5}
    & \setlength\arraycolsep{4pt}
      \ \begin{matrix}
        1 & & & & & \\
        & 1 & & & & \\
        & & 1 & & & \\
        & & & 1 & & \\
        & & & & \ddots & \\
        & & & & & 1
      \end{matrix}
        & & &
    \\\cline{1-3}\cline{5-5}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{%
    \begin{matrix}
      z_1 & z_2 & \cdots & z_N
    \end{matrix}}
    &     
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{%
    \begin{matrix}
      y_1 & y_2 & \cdots & y_h
    \end{matrix}}
  \end{array}
  =s
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

[image]